# Html таблица

Tags: html

Привет всем! Хочу сделать таблицу такого вида:

[image: снимок]

Но получается не так:

```
<table border>
<tr>
<td>img</td><td rowspan="2">Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">kjsdhkgfjdkjghdkhfghk dhfgkhd jfghk ворпловрапо рвбатвьаттвбаьпв баптр влорпваорп</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Или как можно реализовать такую верстку другим способом?

*Заранее благодарю!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вас не устроил ответ где используются блочная верстка (`div`-ы), то наверное можно так:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td >
        <img align="left" style="border:1px sold" ..../>
        ddfgg...
        <br clear="left" />
        ffdmg...
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Вася....</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Воооот БР моей мечты! <br clear="left" /> вот это мне и надобно)) Спасибо большое!

Comment: В самом деле `<br clear="..." />` это не совсем комильфо, просто в вашем случае можно было-бы написать (внутри `<tr>`):

    <div><img align="left" .../>ddfgg...</div>
    <!-- align="left" в img можно заменить на style="float:left" -->
    <div style="clear:left">ffdmg...</div>

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую верстать не таблицами, а используя контейнеры div - это позволяет делать довольно гибкие макеты. То есть вам нужно:

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left">
    <img src="...">
  </div>
  ddfgggg и так далее
</div>
<div>
  Вася петя и т.д.
</div>
```

Посмотрите [руководства от Htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/layout).

Comment: Почему "гибкие" макеты?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что у div значительно большие возможности по размещению объектов (в немногих случаях таблицы будут удобнее).

Comment: все равно одинаково. class или id вот и устанавливаешь стиль=)) Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Почему border в теге table без значения?

Comment: Если установить border без значения, то оно примет значение как по умолчанию "1".

Comment: Так для этого можно было вообще не указывать бордюр